# Putting together a tricky SQL query

Tags: sql-server-2008, select

I am working on a SQL 2008 machine and cannot seem to get the query to work.
My SQL query is :

```
select q.Document DOC from references q, equiprates e where e.MachineID=q.UnitID'
```

The rows retruned by q.Document is:

```
5570_RESTAURANT.pdf  
5650_RESTAURANT.pdf  
5110_RESTAURANT.pdf
```

However, I need the table rows to be as follows:

Restaurant Document

```
<a href="Javascript:ViewPDFDoc('5570_RESTAURANT.pdf')" class="Link">5570_RESTAURANT.pdf</a>  
<a href="Javascript:ViewPDFDoc('5650_RESTAURANT.pdf')" class="Link">5570_RESTAURANT.pdf</a>  
<a href="Javascript:ViewPDFDoc('5110_RESTAURANT.pdf')" class="Link">5570_RESTAURANT.pdf</a>
```

So I am trying to format my selecct string as follows:

```
Select @sSQL = 'select q.Document DOC, ''<a href="Javascript:ViewFile('''''+q.Document+''''''')" class="Link">''+q.Document+''</a>'' ''Restaurant Document'',
from references q, equiprates e 
where e.MachineID=q.UnitID'
```

My error message is:

> Msg 4104, Level 16, State 1, Line 3
>
> The multi-part identifier "q.Document" could not be bound.

Any ideas how to resolve this?
I tried google, but no luck.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Your single quotes are just wrong (I also recommend shifting to more modern INNER JOIN syntax). But why can't the application simply add the HTML around the DOC column? Seems wasteful (never mind more complex, obviously) to add all that HTML at the server, and send all those bytes over the wire.

```
DECLARE @sSQL NVARCHAR(MAX);

SET @sSQL = N'SELECT 
  DOC = q.Document, 
  [Restaurant Document] = ''<a href="Javascript:ViewFile('''''' 
    + q.Document + '''''');" class="Link">'' 
    + q.Document + ''</a>''
  FROM references AS q 
  INNER JOIN equiprates AS e
  ON q.UnitID = e.MachineID';

PRINT @sSQL;
```

Answer (score 1):

try just

```
select 
  '<a href="Javascript:ViewPDFDoc(''' + q.Document + ''')" class="Link">' + q.Document + '</a>'
from
  references q, equiprates e 
where 
  e.MachineID=q.UnitID
```

but remember, it's very bad programming style. it's better when the data model and data view are separated from each other

Comment: your response works for the most part, except that I need the @sSQL = 'select....' as well because there is an if clause where the sql string is modified....