# Creating a hyperlink in a gridview in asp.net (without the hyperlink control)

Tags: asp.net, vb.net, gridview

As a follow up to my previous question [Putting together a tricky SQL query](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/6986799/putting-together-a-tricky-sql-query)

since I now have the records returned as URL format, how can I display those as hyperlinks in my gridview? (this is how the client wants it done, not much I can say to change their mind)

My vb code is:

```
Dim pds As PagedDataSource = New PagedDataSource()
GridView1.DataSource = pds
GridView1.DataBind()
```

Thanks

Answer (score 3, accepted):

You can use a TemplateColumn and build a standard hyperlink in the ItemTemplate.

```
<TemplateColumn>
   <ItemTemplate>
      <a href='<%#Eval("LinkUrl")%>'>Click me</a>
   </ItemTemplate>
</TemplateColumn>
```

Comment: ok, so now I have two columns showing up (one with the hyperlink as you have mentioned in your response "LinkUrl", and one is from the database stored procedure). How do I make the second one disappear?

Comment: Make sure AutoGenerateColumns is set to false. You will have to define the columns that you want to display, but it will give you more control over the display.

Comment: Wait, I think I misunderstood you. Replace "LinkUrl" with the name of the column containing the link.

Comment: Yes, I firgured out that part. Thanks very much for your help.